# Agora RTC with React issue

Tags: reactjs, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am using Agora for the first time and am facing an issue while adding remote streams. When 1st user joins a channel it correctly show it's stream but when another user joins the same channel, the stream of the second user appears on the first user's screen but the stream of first user does not appear on the second user stream. i.e. a user is only able to see the streams of the people joined after it and not of those that joined before it. Below is the code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";
import { options, rtc } from "./constants";
import AgoraRTC from "agora-rtc-sdk-ng";

function App() {
  const RemoteUser = [];
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    try {
      if (channelRef.current.value === "") {
        return console.log("Please Enter Channel Name");
      }

      setJoined(true);

      rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: "rtc", codec: "h264" });
      const uid = await rtc.client.join(
        options.appId,
        channelRef.current.value,
        options.token,
        null
      );

      // Create an audio track from the audio captured by a microphone
      rtc.localAudioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack();
      // Create a video track from the video captured by a camera
      rtc.localVideoTrack = await AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack();

      rtc.localVideoTrack.play("local-stream");



      rtc.client.on("user-published", async (user, mediaType) => {
        // Subscribe to a remote user
    
     
        await rtc.client.subscribe(user);
        console.log("subscribe success");
        // console.log(user);

        if (mediaType === "video" || mediaType === "all") {
          // Get `RemoteVideoTrack` in the `user` object.
          const remoteVideoTrack = user.videoTrack;
          console.log(remoteVideoTrack);

          // Dynamically create a container in the form of a DIV element for playing the remote video track.
          const PlayerContainer = React.createElement("div", {
            id: user.uid,
            className: "stream",
          });
          ReactDOM.render(
            PlayerContainer,
            document.getElementById("remote-stream")
          );

          user.videoTrack.play(`${user.uid}`);
        }

        if (mediaType === "audio" || mediaType === "all") {
          // Get `RemoteAudioTrack` in the `user` object.
          const remoteAudioTrack = user.audioTrack;
          // Play the audio track. Do not need to pass any DOM element
          remoteAudioTrack.play();
        }
      });


     

      rtc.client.on("user-unpublished", (user) => {
        // Get the dynamically created DIV container
    
        const playerContainer = document.getElementById(user.uid);
        console.log(playerContainer);
        // Destroy the container
        playerContainer.remove();
      });

      // Publish the local audio and video tracks to the channel
      await rtc.client.publish([rtc.localAudioTrack, rtc.localVideoTrack]);

      console.log("publish success!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async function handleLeave() {
    try {
      const localContainer = document.getElementById("local-stream");

      rtc.localAudioTrack.close();
      rtc.localVideoTrack.close();

      setJoined(false);
      localContainer.textContent = "";

      // Traverse all remote users
      rtc.client.remoteUsers.forEach((user) => {
        // Destroy the dynamically created DIV container
        const playerContainer = document.getElementById(user.uid);
        playerContainer && playerContainer.remove();
      });

      // Leave the channel
      await rtc.client.leave();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  const [joined, setJoined] = useState(false);
  const channelRef = useRef("");
  const remoteRef = useRef("");
  const leaveRef = useRef("");

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={channelRef}
          id="channel"
          placeholder="Enter Channel name"
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Join"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
          disabled={joined ? true : false}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          ref={leaveRef}
          value="Leave"
          onClick={handleLeave}
          disabled={joined ? false : true}
        />
      </div>
      {joined ? (
        <>
          <div id="local-stream" className="stream local-stream"></div>
          <div
            id="remote-stream"
            ref={remoteRef}
            className="stream remote-stream"
          ></div>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the 'stream-subscribed' listener?

Comment: @Ankit, Did you find any solution? I am facing a similar issue. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

create rtcClient outside the function handleSubmit.

Also register the events when document/Page is ready.

```
rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: "rtc", codec: "h264" });
rtc.client.on("user-published", async (user, mediaType) => {
     //Your code
}
            
rtc.client.on("user-unpublished", (user) => {
     //Your code
}
```

It will show the users list accurately.